# Compare all elements of two collections and produce a third one

Tags: scala, collections, nested-loops, scala-collections, for-comprehension

I am looking for a nice way to compare the elements of two Scala collections and produce a third collection based on a condition. I can sacrifice code appearance for performance.

Assuming the following:

```
case class Item(name: String, category: String, code: String, price: Int, freeItem: Option[Item])

val parentItems = Seq(
  Item("name_1", "category_A", "code_A", 100, None),
  Item("name_2", "category_B", "code_B", 100, None),
  Item("name_3", "category_C", "code_C", 100, None)
)

val childItems = Seq(
  Item("name_4", "category_A", "code_A", 100, None),
  Item("name_5", "category_C", "code_C", 100, None)
)

def isChild(i1: Item, i2: Item): Boolean = {
  i1.name != i2.name &&
    i1.category == i2.category &&
    i1.code == i2.code
}

val parentsWithChildren: Seq[Item] = (
  for {
    i1 <- parentItems;
    i2 <- childItems
  } yield {
    if (isChild(i1, i2)) Some(i1.copy(freeItem = Some(i2.copy())))
    else None
  }).filter(_.isInstanceOf[Some[_]]).map(_.get)
```

The above snippet will produce the following result, which is the excpected:

```
Seq(
  Item("name_1", "category_A", "code_A", 100, 
    Some(Item("name_4", "category_A", "company_A", 100, None))),
  Item("name_3", "category_C", "code_C", 100, 
    Some(Item("name_5", "category_C", "company_C", 100, None)))
)
```

I know that the above code has loopholes but that's fine. What I am looking for is:

1. Is there any way I can avoid the if (isChild(i1, i2)) `Some(i1.copy(freeItem = Some(i2.copy()))) else None` and as a result the `.filter(_.isInstanceOf[Some[_]]).map(_.get)`? Would Partial Function be an option?
2. I am using nested loop here, I would do something like that in Java. Is there any other way to approach it? I thought I `zip` at first but obviously doesn't work, by itself at least.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be tempted to try something like this:

```
val parentsWithChildren: Seq[Item] =
  for {
    parent <- parentItems
    child <- childItems if isChild(parent, child)
  }
    yield parent.copy(freeItem = Some(child))
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `1`, returning an Option seems like the right thing to do, but you can replace the filter with flatten:

```
(for {
    i1 <- parentItems;
    i2 <- childItems
  } yield {
    if (isChild(i1, i2)) Some(i1.copy(freeItem = Some(i2.copy())))
    else None
  }).flatten
```

As for `2`, if you really need a nested loop and you are worried about performance, your code looks good to me. Maybe someone has a better idea.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question. `flatten` work well and produce the expected result. However, @Martin made it even more compact. I think both implementation should perform more or less the same.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly unorthodox approach, but one that I believe would be more performant, would be to concatenate `category` and `code` to form the key to a map with a `groupBy`:

```
val childItemMap: Map[String, Iterable[Item]] = childItems
   .groupBy(item => s"${item.category}-${item.code}")
```

Then you just iterate over `parentItem`s, concatenate *their* categories and codes, and copy the map values into the parents:

```
val parentsWithChildren: Seq[Item] = parentItems
   .map { p => 
      p.copy(freeItem = childItemMap.get(s"${p.category}-${p.code}").map(_.head))
   }
```

Your data model suggests there is only one possible match, so I am only grabbing the first (and presumably only) matching value. I am using `head` rather than `headOption` because I generated the `Map` with a `groupBy`, so there never would be an empty value. The result is a `Seq[Item]` with the child matches copied into the parents.

Comment: Thank you for providing this answer. It works perfectly fine in my case, but I have slightly more complicated models and it becomes difficult for other people to follow. I didn't measure its performance, but you can be right about it :)

Comment: That's fine, but I still think you should consider using a `Map`-based approach--even if it isn't literally the one I describe.